# Error Installing Fedora 24

Tags: fedora, boot, system-installation

I've created a bootable fedora usb with UnetBootin, but When I attempt to install Fedora, It gives me the following error before I can get to the main install screen

```
    dract-initqueue[519] Warning: Could not boot
    dract-initqueue[519] Warning: /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-KDE-Live-24-1-2 does not exist
    dract-initqueue[519] Warning: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist

    Starting Setup Virtual Console ..
    Starting Dracut Emergency Shell
    Warning: /dev/disk/by-label/Fedora-KDE-Live-24-1-2 does not exist
    Warning: /dev/mapper/live-rw does not exist

    Generating "run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"

    Entering emergency mode ...
```

I've also tried using the non spin gnome iso, but it shows me the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of FC20 (at least, I don't remember the starting release) Fedora does support only one way of creating bootable `USB` from `iso` image: it's a raw copy of an image to a block device. Any tools like `Live USB Creator` may produce unpredictable results.

You could use `dd` utility to accomplish this task:

```
dd if=/path/to/image of=/dev/sdX
```

where `/dev/sdX` is a device node of an inserted `USB` flash stick.

An alternative copy method is provided in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, fedora does gives these kind of errors, I had too.
But here the culprit is Unetbootin. Unetbootin works best with Ubuntu based distros.

Try making bootable disk with **'Disks'**(comes pre-installed with Fedora and Ubuntu).
Follow the below steps. Hope it will guide you.

- Go to '**Disks**'
- **Select the device** you want to make bootable,
- Click on the **Hamburger menu** on top and select '**Restore Disk Image**',
- Select the .iso file and press '**Start Recording**'.
- **Restart** the system and it will welcome you with start sreen!